# Books for experimental scattering experiments

Tags: quantum-field-theory, experimental-physics, resource-recommendations, collision, scattering

I am searching for introductory books that explains in pedagogical way how scattering experiments are done  .
I  want to understand  how the experimental apparatus works and how experiments are done. For example in electron electron scattering I want to know what are the initial condition of the electrons like impact parameter, momentum etc,and how the detectors are placed.